# Issue copying invoice data from one sheet to another when payment is selected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copying

I am looking to save products that are chosen in an invoice to another sheet in the same workbook when a payment method is selected. Here is [a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VmJdVe_g1fgqmRyOlAAA0Zgvvul1W-knokaNdDHj10A/edit?usp=sharing) of the sheet. How the sheet works:

1) User places "x" into selection column in "Protocol Selection" (WORKING)

2) In the next sheet in the workbook "Patient Invoice", an invoice with bottle count is generated (WORKING)

3) I want the past invoices (with product, date, pill-count, etc.) to be copied over to the "Past Invoices" sheet when the "Method of Payment" is selected. This is a drop-down Data Validation cell. (NOT WORKING)

Is there a way to do this without a custom script? IF not, what is the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient method but it does work...

**Script**

```
function makePastInvoice() {
  var patientInvoice = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Patient Invoice');
  var pastInvoices = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Past Invoices');

  // vistor details
  var visitDate = patientInvoice.getRange("D3").getValue();
  var patientName = patientInvoice.getRange("G5").getValue();
  var doctorName = patientInvoice.getRange("I5").getValue();
  var programLength = patientInvoice.getRange("I3").getValue();
  var invoiceNumber = patientInvoice.getRange("G3").getValue();
  var total = patientInvoice.getRange("K30").getValue();
  var paymentMethod = patientInvoice.getRange("D5").getValue();
  var visitorDetails = [visitDate, patientName, doctorName, programLength, invoiceNumber, total, paymentMethod];

  var lastRow = pastInvoices.getLastRow();
  var currentRow = lastRow + 1;

  // set values of patient details to Past Invoices sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < visitorDetails.length; i++) {
    pastInvoices.getRange(currentRow, i+1).setValue(visitorDetails[i]);
  }

  // 15 possible max items (per Past Invoices)
  var productIDs = patientInvoice.getRange("A8:A22").getValues();

  // count number of products
  var productCount = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < productIDs.length; i++) {
    if (productIDs[i] > "") {
      productCount++;
    }
  }

  // Patient Invoice
  var firstItemRow = 8;

  // Past Invoices
  var firstItemCol = 8 // column H

  // loop through purchases
  for(var i = 0; i < productCount; i++) { 

    // purchase details
    var productName = patientInvoice.getRange(firstItemRow, 2).getValue(); // col B 
    var dosage = patientInvoice.getRange(firstItemRow, 5).getValue(); // col E
    var numBottles = patientInvoice.getRange(firstItemRow, 6).getValue(); // col F 
    var purchaseDetails = [productName, dosage, numBottles];

    // set values of purchase details to Past Invoices sheet
    for(var j = 0; j < purchaseDetails.length; j++) {
      pastInvoices.getRange(currentRow, firstItemCol).setValue(purchaseDetails[j])
      firstItemCol ++;
    }
    firstItemRow++;
  }
}
```

**Trigger**

I'm sure there's a way to trigger the script when the payment method changes or any other method of choice but I created a "submit" trigger with a `drawing` and assigned it to the `makePastInvoice` function.

[image]

Also, you'll probably want to change the "Visit Date" column's format to `date`.

Comment: Thanks iMarketingGuy! The script works great. You are quite talented.

Comment: lol thanks. I'm glad it works. I know very little but have an interest in learning more. I created several 'unnecessary' variables for the sake of logic readability. Hopefully you didn't have any issues with creating a trigger.